# Does `&mut T` implement `Copy` or not?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

Consider this code:

```rust
struct A;

trait Test {
    fn test(self);
}

impl Test for &mut A {
    fn test(self) {
        println!("&mut Test called");
    }
}

fn test(a: &mut A) {
    a.test();
}

fn test2(a: impl Test) {
    a.test();
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A;

    let a_mut_ref = &mut a;

    test(a_mut_ref); // works fine
    test(a_mut_ref); // works fine

    test2(a_mut_ref); // `a_mut_ref` moved here? Why?
    test2(a_mut_ref); // compile error `use of moved value` here
}
```

According to Rust's [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#impl-Copy-72), mutable references do not implement `Copy`.

1. Why does calling `test` twice work fine?
2. Why does not it work with `test2` the same way?
3. How can I change `test2` to keep both impl-like boundary and get successful compilation?

Comment: Look up [reborrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.12.0/nomicon/references.html#liveness), currently still [lacking](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788) in docs.

Comment: It's complicated

Comment: Update definition of `test2` to `fn test2<T: Test + Copy>(a: T)`, then you'll see a better error message for your question.

Comment: **1** reborrows, as linked previously and explained in the duplicates. **2** Because `impl Trait` introduces a generic, and further explained in the duplicates. **3** you cannot currently, as explained in the duplicates.